# django navbar how I do pass the product pk to each different link

Tags: django, django-templates

This is a question about how to pass a Product model pk to a navbar where the call can originate from different pages / views, ie not always from the product details page.

I'm using a base template for my navbar and then I have an html page and a view for each link in the navbar like this:

Product Details - `product_form.html` - `views.ProductUpdateView.as_view()`

Colours - `productcolours_list.html` - `views.ProductColourListView.as_view()`

[my nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Rfb.png)

The idea of the navbar is that once I'm looking at Product A for example, I can click through between the product details page, the product colours, and then the bill of materials. This is what the navbar code looks like:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'ProductUpdateView' pk=product.pk %}">Product Details</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'ProductColourListView' pk=product.pk %}">Colours</a>
  </li>
```

The problem is that this works only when I'm on the Product Details page because the base template can interpret what product.pk is. But as soon as I click to go to the Colours link in the navbar, it tries to render the base template and all of the sudden it has no idea what product.pk is.

This is because the Product Details page uses the Product model through ProductUpdateView (which I can then reference product.pk with) but the Colours page uses the ProductColour model through ProductColourListView which in that case it would be colours.product.pk.

It's like I need the base template to understand where to grab the pk from depending on whether I'm coming from the Product Details page, the Colours page or some other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put the product in the context in the view that does not manipulate your product as the single object ?

```python
class ProductColourListView(generic.ListView):
    model = models.ProductColour

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('product', put_here_your_product)
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you @mistiru. I didn't realise that you could do that. I'm a bit new to class based views and that these classes have predefined methods that you can override. Thanks again that was really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome! Class based view can be a little confusing at first as there is a lot of hidden work done in a lot of different places, but you'll quickly get used ;)